# Selenium webdriver: if condition for a long list of objects

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, automation, webdriver

Is there a way I can simplify the code below?

```
public static void InputData(){
 //Lastname
 if (driver.findElements(By.id("last_name")).size() != 0) {  
 driver.findElement(By.id("last_name")).sendKeys("MARSUPIAL");
 } 
 //Fistname
 if (driver.findElements(By.id("first_name")).size() != 0) {  
 driver.findElement(By.id("first_name")).sendKeys("MARK"); 
 } 

}
```

I have  20 items with the same 'if' scenario

instead of doing "if object exist write 'x'" per text box is there a way to write it in a single if statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibility is to put the key's in a `Map` and
iterate over the `Map` for validation:

```
final Map<String,String> lAllKeys = new HashMap<>();
lAllKeys.put("last_name","MARSUPIAL");
lAllKeys.put("first_name", "MARK");
for (String lKey : lAllKeys.keySet()) {
  if (driver.findElements(By.id(lKey)).size() != 0) {  
     driver.findElement(By.id(lKey)).sendKeys(lAllKeys.get(lKey));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan what if i have another set but instead of using sendkeys, is should click the object eg if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='checkbox1']")).size() != 0) {  
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='checkbox1']")).click();
          }

Comment: that you can handle with maps too